# Time complexity of below pseudocode

Tags: time-complexity, big-o, pseudocode

```
void buzz(int num, int [] a)
{
    for(int i=1;i<num;i*=2){
      for(int j=0;j<a[i]%num;j++){
          print(num);
      }
    }
}
```

I understand that the outer for loop runs for log n times. Need help in understanding the complexity of the inner loop and the overall.

Comment: Depends on the values of `a[i]`, which aren't shown. If they're constant, if they're effectively a function of `i`, etc.

Comment: @Useless: you know that `0 ≤ a[i] % num < num`

Answer (score 1):

Let us assume `num = 2^n` for simplicity.

The inner loop runs `a[i] % num` times, which is comprised in range `[0, num-1]`. The outer loop runs `n` times so you can conclude `O(num.log(num)) = O(n.2^n)` worst-case complexity.

---

For a precise evaluation, let `r[i] := a[i] % num`. Then the number of print's is

```
r[1] + r[2] + r[4] + r[8] + ... r[2^(n-1)].
```

This is `n` times the average `r` (for the relevant indexes; the expectation of `r` could be `(num-1)/2)`).